# Function returns tuple instead of string

Tags: python, string, function, python-2.7, tuples

I have a function in python similar to the following:

```
def checkargs(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        x = args
        y = something
    elif len(args) == 2:
        x, y = args

    return x, y
```

When I put in only one argument (a string), x comes out as a tuple. When I put in two arguments (two strings), x and y are returned as strings. How can I get x to come out as string if I only put in one argument?

Comment: Don't use `*args` for this.  `def checkargs(x, y=something, *args)` would accomplish what you want, and be clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because `args` is *always* a tuple, even if you only put in one argument. So, when you do:

```
x = args
```

This is like doing:

```
x = ('abc',)
```

There are two (equivalent) ways to fix this: either explicitly assign `x` to the first element of the tuple:

```
x = args[0]
```

or invoke the same tuple unpacking that the `x,y` assignment uses by assigning to a length-1 tuple:

```
x, = args
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def checkargs(*args):
    try:
      x, y = args
    except ValueError:
      (x,), y = args, 'something'
    return x, y
```

However, if you are going to check for the presence of `y` and assign it to a default `something` when it's not there, consider redesigning the interface to simply use a default kwarg instead.